# User Authentication on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, php, github-pages, static-site

I am trying to build a website on GitHub pages. This website will have User Authentication ( think of Login ). Each user will have some private pages which only he is able to access. Since GitHub only allows Static Sites, I am unsure if this is even possible here.

Since I am a complete novice to website development I don't know how this will work/ whether this will even work ?

I know that GitHub Pages do not support PHP but they do support JavaScript, thus is there any way possible for this to be implemented ( even if it includes using third party apps/ websites )?

Comment: "I know that GitHub Pages do not support PHP but they do support JavaScript" — They do not support any kind of server side code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.

> GitHub only allows Static Sites

So you won't be able to store any user sessions on Github. There's likely something "creative" you can do to manage users or sessions using Javascript and/or by making requests to 3rd party sites but it's likely not going to be worth the effort, especially if you are a complete novice to web development.

Many web hosting providers offer free or trial accounts, I would suggest trying those or running a VM locally while you learn.

Comment: Of course it's entirely up to you to decide. Best of luck.

Comment: Well, Thanks for your reply. 
However the reason for hosting my website as a static website is that contains static webpages (think of something like blog posts)  but the only thing 'dynamic' about it is user authentication. 
That's why if it is possible, then I will at-least try it.

Comment: @YamanSingla This answer is correct. You **might** be able to do something like create a client-side JavaScript application that "restricts" users somehow, but note that all of your content is public on GitHub anyway. Please be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KevinWorkman The content will be in a private repo. I am just trying to authenticate users and based on their authentication status I will be showing them the content. Does that make it somewhat clear?

Comment: @YamanSingla Perhaps, but the answer doesn't change. You might be able to do something with JavaScript, but if you're a complete novice this probably won't exactly be trivial. Try to start smaller: can you create a JavaScript app that shows a login prompt and only shows some content after the user types a username into the prompt? Worry about actually checking the authentication only after you get this piece working. But even then, your pages will be publicly available on the internet for anybody who can figure out the URL. You need a server to properly do this.